# android enableDexingArtifactTransform desugaring false

Tags: android, performance, webrtc, build.gradle

In our react native application, we use webrtc for video calls and i can see that webrtc is getting crash in few android devices. When i check solutions for this it mentioned in some of the links(https://github.com/react-native-webrtc/react-native-webrtc/blob/master/Documentation/AndroidInstallation.md) that we need to add below to fix this issue

```
 android.enableDexingArtifactTransform.desugaring=false
```

**But when i add above does this impact on build time, .dex file size, and runtime performance of application?**